# Running Jest from Visual Studio Code in Windows results in no tests being found

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, jestjs

For some reason, running jest via Visual Studio code returns something akin to the following:

`running command> jest --no-cache
No tests found
In c:\Users\gusta\Documents\ts
  992 files checked.
  testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.js?(x),**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x) - 121 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: \\node_modules\\ - 7 matches
Pattern: "" - 0 matches`

However when running the tests from the command line, it resolves the tests just fine.

`C:\Users\gusta\Documents\ts>jest --no-cache
 PASS  src\__test__\some-component.test.jsx (6.812s)`

This happens both when trying to debug in VSCode, but also simply when running a task. My tasks.json looks like this:

`{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
        "taskName": "jest",
        "command": "jest",
        "args": [
            "--no-cache"
        ],
        "isShellCommand": true,
        "echoCommand": true,
        "showOutput": "always"
        }
    ]
}`

My package.json:

`{
    "name": "badgeexplorerts",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "android": "yarn run haul start -- --platform android",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/jest": "^19.2.3",
        "react": "~15.4.1",
        "react-native": "0.42.3",
        "ts-loader": "^2.0.3",
        "typescript": "^2.2.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/react": "^15.0.24",
        "@types/react-native": "^0.43.12",
        "babel-jest": "^20.0.0",
        "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "haul-cli": "^0.5.0",
        "jest": "^20.0.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "~15.4.1",
        "ts-jest": "^20.0.2"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    }
}`

Does anyone know what's going on? My version of VSCode is 1.12.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out that if you change your "version" to 2.0.0 it works just fine.
I can't explain that, but a task.json that works looks like this:

`{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
        "taskName": "jest",
        "command": "jest",
        "args": [
            "--no-cache"
        ],
        "isShellCommand": true,
        "echoCommand": true,
        "showOutput": "always"
        }
    ]

}`

I had the same problem with a node debug configuration, where setting

`"console": "integratedTerminal"`
inside the launch.json made it work. I can't explain it, but it works for me.